# Postgres stored procedure call to extension dll is changing text parameter to utf8

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a Postgres stored procedure that calls an extension dll function with a text parameter. If I iterate the string in the stored procedure before the call to the extension dll, it shows the correct characters in the string:

H       ú   a  v   e   r   i   m      m  a   k       ú   s   h   i   v   i   m
72;204;163;97;118;101;114;105;109;32;109;97;107;204;163;115;104;105;118;105;109  ==> as seen in the script

When I iterate the string in the C extension dll function, it looks like some bytes are replaced with their UTF8 characters representation (I think)?:

72;195;140;194;163;97;118;101;114;105;109;32;109;97;107;195;140;194;163;115;104;105;118;105;109; ==> as seen in extension dll

I need the extension dll function to see the string as it is seen in the stored procedure before the call. Help please.

Comment: Please include the code that is iterating over this data.

Comment: It is strange - postgres doesn't does it. Maybe you have wrong client_encoding?